# Using Topic Filters in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

This [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters) describes the concept of topic filters, but I can't see an equivalent in the new `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`.  The previous way would be something like:

```
var filter = new CorrelationFilter();
filter.To = "test";
var ruleDescription = new RuleDescription("rulename", filter);
await subscriptionClient.AddRuleAsync(ruleDescription);
```

Please can someone point me to documentation, or give some guidance as to how this is dealt with by the new SDK?

Comment: The namespace you would want to look into is [`Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration?view=azure-dotnet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from Gaurav Mantri is correct; topic filters and other resource management is done using the [`ServiceBusAdministrationClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient) from the `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` package.

General use of the administration client is covered in [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample07_CrudOperations.md) and there is a dedicated [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/TopicFilters) available that demonstrates working with topic filters.  The topic filter sample can also be downloaded directly through the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/topic-filters) site.